# Power BI: Order data by YearMonth in DAX

Tags: date, powerbi, dax

I would like to create a `YearMonth` column in Power BI and group data in this order in visual plot, say histogram.

I tried to create a duplicate of the datetime column `MY_DATE`(format: `05-10-2018 12:00:00 AM`) and convert it to `Year-Month` format in the `ColumnTools` ribon:

[image]

Although in the column the format looks correct, eg., '2018-03', when I plot the graph after grouping by `YearMonth` it is repeating itself, ie., having multiple columns of `2018-07`.

Then I tried creating `YearMonth` with:

```
YearMonthText = YEAR(Table[MY_DATE]) & "-" & MONTH(Table[MY_DATE])
```

This looks good in both table column and was able to aggregate data when grouped by `YearMonth`, however, the table is not in chronological order, eg.:

```
2020-10   2020-11   2020-12   2020-7   2020-8   2020-9   2021-1   2021-2   ...
```

How can I get the plot to show data in chronological order?

Comment: You have to have a leading zero when you have single digit month number, e.g. 2020-07 that should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

First, use:

```
YearMonthText = YEAR(Table[MY_DATE]) & "-" & MONTH(Table[MY_DATE])
```

to get `YearMonth` in text format(eg., `2018-3`).

Then, convert `Data type` to `Date` type in ColumnTools ribon.